# Using a stored procedure as an if expression

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I'm trying to use a stored procedure inside a if expression but it doesn't work.

I can workaround the problem with a variable initialized by the stored procedure before the if statement but I would really like know why I can not do it on a single line?

Here is the code :

```
DELIMITER $$$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_IsTableExists`
$$$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_IsTableExists`(IN ptablename VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN (select COUNT(*)
   from information_schema.COLUMNS
   where TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   and TABLE_NAME = ptablename) = 0 THEN false ELSE true END AS exist FROM DUAL;
END;
$$$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_IsTableCreated`
$$$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_IsTableCreated`(IN ptablename VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  IF (sp_IsTableExists(ptablename)) THEN
    SELECT TRUE FROM DUAL;
  ELSE
    SELECT FALSE FROM DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
$$$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_IsTableCreated2`
$$$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_IsTableCreated2`(IN ptablename VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  IF (  SELECT CASE WHEN (select COUNT(*)
   from information_schema.COLUMNS
   where TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   and TABLE_NAME = ptablename) = 0 THEN false ELSE true END AS exist FROM DUAL) THEN
    SELECT TRUE FROM DUAL;
  ELSE
    SELECT FALSE FROM DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
$$$$
```

Calling "call sp_IsTableCreated('Utilisateur')" gives "#1305 - FUNCTION (...).sp_IsTableExists does not exist.".

Calling "call sp_IsTableCreated2('Utilisateur')" works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write SQL code of the form `IF(stored_code(param, param))`, the object called `stored_code` needs to be a stored *function*, not a stored procedure.

Don't forget to declare functions like the one you're showing with the characteristics `NOT DETERMINISTIC` and `READS SQL DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a function instead of stored procedure.

```
use test; -- use your database

delimiter  $$$$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `sp_IsTableExists` $$$$
CREATE FUNCTION `sp_IsTableExists`(ptablename VARCHAR(50))
returns bool
BEGIN


  select COUNT(*) into @count
   from information_schema.COLUMNS
   where TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   and TABLE_NAME = ptablename ;

  return @count <> 0;
END;
$$$$

-- usage:
select sp_IsTableExists('tablename');
```